# Cannot resolve GoogleSignIn and GoogleSignInClient

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth

I am not able to use GoogleSignIn(*com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn*
) and GoogleSignInClient(*com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient*
) while implementing Google Sign In in Android Studio while I can access other classes in App like

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
```

A strip down version of my build.gradle(app) file is as follow

```
android {

}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev72-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my build.gradle(package) is

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you get any error than add your logcat.

Comment: Do you have `Google Repository` installed in your SDK Manager?

Comment: @Yupi Yes, I am using the latest version of Google Repository.

Answer (score 30):

add this to your app-level dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer.

Comment: find all the list of dependencies here . https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I got latest version for today  "16.0.0"

Answer (score 16):

I was having the same issue

**GoogleSignIn** and **GoogleSignInClient** were introduced in version Google Play services SDK version 11.6. In older versions GoogleApiClient was used.

So try changing the compile **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'** to  **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'** in dependencies

**dependencies 
{
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'` 
 }**

Answer (score 5):

For me I was applying a plugin for the google play services in my **app's build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

along with that in my **Project's Build.gradle** I had google services.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2' // <== this guy
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I remember I added them with some compiling issues. But apparently I didn't need them.

**By removing them I found there were no more issues with the gms versions.**

**EDIT**

So removing solved my issue initially, but gave me issues later with google sign in. adding the **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** to the bottom of my projects gradle instead of at the top did actually solve it.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to the bottom of my projects gradle instead of at the top solve it.

Comment: Me as well, I had implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0' so I didn't think it was a version issue. Removing the plugin line completely fixed the missing GoogleSignIn references, but does not work. Adding the plug-in line by itself to the end of the file seems to have worked.  This seems like a bug (maybe a namespace bug) in the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

In the **build.gradle** Module script, I had to add these two dependencies, then "Sync Now" and issue resolved for me.

```
dependencies {  
    // Your own command lines
    //...

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use any newer version? e.g. 11.6.0.
Try to update your Google Repository as well. 
(Tools->Android->SDK Manager->SDK Tools under Support Repository)

Comment: +1. 11.6.0 is minimum required version for GoogleSignIn / GoogleSignInClient classes (older versions have slightly different class names)

Comment: But there are one issue, com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2 is included version 11.4.2, and its become a conflict with versions 11.4.2 and 11.6.0 , and new version is not available on google-services.

Comment: @VaheGharibyan I am able to use them without any problem. Could you specify what the problem is?

Comment: @pcforgeek I have got an Dex exception that some libraries are duplicated.
When I add this line classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2', its add external library firebase 11.4.2, and play-services-auth:11.6.0 integrate external library  firebase 11.6.0, that's why gradle throw dex error

Comment: @VaheGharibyan If you are getting the following message "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2." Then you can fix by moving apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the end of build.gradle(app) file.

Comment: @pcforgeek  I forced to use api 11.4.2, but the problem is, api 11.4.2 does not contain GoogleSignIn / GoogleSignInClient classes.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this, I'd like to use 11.6.0 as well

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix I have mentioned the solution to this in my previous comment.

Comment: @pcforgeek thanks )) I moved apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' and 11.4.2 removed from external libraries

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in build.gradle module file under dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
```

For example:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


}
```

Comment: No need to add `Firebase` dependency, as `GoogleSignIn` and `GooglSignInClient` are under the Google Play Services.