# Cannot resolve GoogleSignInClient

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate Google Sign-In in Android Studio and am not able to use GoogleSignIn and GoogleSignInClient. I understood from similar issues that the com.google.firebase:firebase-auth version should be at least '11.6.0', but the version in my app build.gradle is higher ('16.0.3') as you can see:

My app build.gradle dependencies:

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

My project build.gradle dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224177/cannot-resolve-googlesignin-and-googlesigninclient

Answer (score 4):

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
```

Make sure they're are in your code.

In your build app gradle file:

```
dependencies {    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
```

}

add this below

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add google repository on your gradle build

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    } }
```

Please see this link for more detail : https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup