# Xamarin Android: Cannot resolve GoogleSignIn and GoogleSignInClient

Tags: android, xamarin, google-api, xamarin.android, google-oauth

I am not able to use GoogleSignIn(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn ) and GoogleSignInClient(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient ) while implementing Google Sign In in Visual Studio with Xamarin Android while I can access other classes in App like:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
```

This is the guide I am following: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Aditional, I was looking for similar post in Java and other IDE like this post:
[Cannot resolve GoogleSignIn and GoogleSignInClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224177/cannot-resolve-googlesignin-and-googlesigninclient)

But, in my case the issue is in Xamarin Android with Visual Studio.

I tried with oficcial and preliminar version of the nuget Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity:

[image]

Then, I tried with all nutgets avaliables in official and preliminar version of GooglePlayServices:

[image]

And this is another post It doesn't work in my case, because the version Nutget doesn't avaliable: [How do you integrate the new Google Sign-In on a Xamarin.Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639015/how-do-you-integrate-the-new-google-sign-in-on-a-xamarin-android-app/34642070)

```
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity 29.0.0-beta1
```

Finally, I have configured the Google Repository Tool in the SDK Manager too:
[image]

Comment: I was searching in https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient but I culdn't resolve the issue

Comment: Here is a google-signin samle for reference.https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/SigninQuickstart/

Comment: Even up till now, the latest nuget package has not solved this issue. The GoogleSignIn and GoogleSignInClient classes are still missing. Please has anyone been able to resolve it?

Comment: These classes are still missing as of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity v 117.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth fixed the problem for me.