# Why does GoogleApiClient.Build.EnableAutoManage softlock my application?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-api-client

### Summary

I have a Xamarin application which creates a GoogleApiClient and calls EnableAutoManage. When my app runs, I am asked which user account to use, and then the app hangs on a blank popup page with a Google-themed spinner. Why is this happening?

### Details

I have been following this video which shows how to set up an application's to read Google Fit data. Notice the timestamp - this is where the code is presented.

https://youtu.be/j_zsNxMI6jI?t=2172

I have followed the examples here, and have narrowed the problem to this piece of code:

```
// In my MainActivity's OnCreate:
try
{
    int defaultClientId = 0;
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .AddApi(FitnessClass.HISTORY_API)
        .AddApi(FitnessClass.RECORDING_API)
        .AddScope(FitnessClass.ScopeActivityRead)
        .EnableAutoManage(this, defaultClientId, 
        result => 
        {
            int m = 3; // Breakpoint here is never hit
        })
        .Build();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    int m = 3; // Breakpoint here is never hit either
}
```

If I run my app (tried on both emulator and physical hardware), I am first asked which account to use.

[image: Account Selection]

After selecting the account, another popup appears with a Google-themed (changing between red, yellow, green, and blue) spinner at the top. The popup stays on screen and the spinner animates indefinitely.

[image]

As noted in the code above, no exceptions are raised, and no result is returned in the EnableAutoManage delegate. Why is this happening?

### Update 1

If I remove the following line, the app no longer shows a spinner indefinitely:

```
.AddScope(FitnessClass.ScopeActivityRead)
```

The addition of this line of code seems to be the cause of the popup with the spinner.

### Update 2

I thought I'd try the "new" approach of using GoogleApi rather than GoogleApiClient as explained here:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html

Unfortunately, there seem to be no Xamarin bindings for this yet:

[Xamarin Android: Cannot resolve GoogleSignIn and GoogleSignInClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468727/xamarin-android-cannot-resolve-googlesignin-and-googlesigninclient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happened is because my google account hadn't yet been added as a test user. One might expect that Google would provide some kind of useful feedback through a popup, but instead it provided an empty page.

To solve this problem:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard
2. Click on OAuth consent screen [image: consent screen]
3. Scroll down to the **Test Users** section [image: Test Users]
4. Enter the email addresses of the test users you would like to use testing your app (such as your own personal gmail)

Now the app should properly display a confirmation page.